# WooCommerce – Issue while removing country field in the account pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm facing an issue while attempting to remove the country field from the account and checkout forms of WooCommerce, and I am unsure how to resolve it.

I have used the "woocommerce_default_address_fields" filter to unset the field, which successfully remove it from the forms. However, when trying to add a new address on the account page, the form fails to submit and it just jumps me to the top of the page like when there is a field error.

```
function custom_remove_address_fields( $fields ) {
    unset( $fields['country'] );

    return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields', 'custom_remove_address_fields' );
```

I only sell in one country and having this field is unnecessary for me. I know I can easily just hide the field with CSS, but I would like to completely remove it if possible :)

If you have any suggestions or ideas, they would be greatly appreciated.

Current environment:
WordPress: Version 6.2
WooCommerce: Version 7.5.1
Theme: Storefront Version: 4.2.0

Answer (score 1):

This is not a bug.
https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/17116

The option to hide the country, is using CSS.
In the WooCommerce settings set the store to sell and ship to only one country. Then, since the country field will be disabled, you can just hide it using CSS.